# Setting serviceURI for ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-services, client

I'm searching a way to set the serviceURI for ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider in code behind. I wish not to have the app.config being changed. Is this possible ?

I'm accessing services from a windows service as well as from a windows program and configuration should be handled in a central place.

Thanks,
Sascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to cast to ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider  just before doing the authentication. If casted you have a property ServiceUri. Set it and it's done.